# How large are in-wall heating vents that connect to registers?

Tags: drywall, framing, interior, ducts

I'm curious how large heating vents can typically be when connecting to in-wall registers.  Do they fill up the entire space between studs?

I'm framing for some drywall patches and would ideally not like to make life too much harder when we get central heating (a couple years from now).

-M

Comment: Not an HVAC expert, but I think it depends on the size of the space to be heated and the size of the HVAC system.  From what I've typically seen cold air returns take up the entire gap between the studs, but heat vents do not.

Comment: Is there something about your house that makes you think the new registers would need to go in the walls?  I think that typically when central HVAC is retrofitted registers are placed in the floor or ceiling, where there's easy access from the basement/crawlspace or attic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link to a manufacturer of [various types of wall ducts](http://www.standexadp.com/catstyle.php?prodcode=FG36&groupname=Wallstack%20Fittings); the [wallstack](http://www.standexadp.com/catproduct.php?mapref=sysmappr.htm&style=200) and [register stackheads](http://www.standexadp.com/catproduct.php?style=26&stylename=Register%20Stackhead) page shows the size of openings that you can have.  Looks like your choices are 2 1/4" or 3 1/4" deep, by 10", 12" or 14" wide.